Set custom Month for HighLevel Calendar Widget
I have a custom calendar widget in GoHighLevel CRM, and I'm looking to display a specific month to the user by passing the month number or name as a query parameter in the widget's iframe URL. Is there a way to achieve this and show a custom month to the user without relying on pre-set configurations?
I’ve tried several approaches, such as passing month=7, month=january, and month=feb, but haven't been able to get the desired result. However, the widget is working fine for passing parameters like contact name and email.
Sample: https://GOHIHGLEVEL.com/widget/booking/csdfewfftrgadDVSssk?month=feb
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!
